# Confused with updating a newcommand constant inside a foreach loop

Tags: foreach, variable

I am confused on how to update a "constant" construct inside a \foreach loop, the similar questions on here don't directly address the issue I am facing and I'm not experimented enough (yet! ;) in LaTeX to figure it out by myself.

I believe the issue arise from the \const definition. I have tested replacing \global\edef by \glet,\csglet, \gletcs and \csgletcs (quite blindly, but was suggested in a couple of answers on here) to no avail.

I'd appreciate any help on this matter,

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% ---- Helper function: easily add values to variables
%      Taken from a reply on stackoverflow that I can't find back...
%.     Works like so \const{VariableName}{value} ex: \const{CoolVariable}{5}
%.     and can then be called with \CoolVariable
%.     and can be updates with \const{CoolVariable}{CoolVariable+10}
\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
   \global\edef\temporary{round(#3}%
   \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
}


% ---- Set dummy variable 
\const{MyVariable}{1}

% ---- I want to loop over a list of keywords with the name of "MyVariable"
%.     Only one here for example.
\newcommand\MyVariableList{MyVariable}

% ---- Start the loop and update values of constants in MyVariableList
\foreach \variable in \MyVariableList{
   % ---- This updates the variable \MyVariable correctly
   \const{\csname variable\endcsname}{\csname variable\endcsname +20}
   
   % ---- Values of \MyVariable changes within the loop
   MyVariable inside the loop: \csname \variable\endcsname
}

\begin{document}

MyVariable outisde the loop: 
% ---- But not outside of it 
\MyVariable

\end{document}
```

[image: ExampleOutput]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\foreach` puts each iteration inside a group. Because of this you need to make the assignment to your variable global.

The following uses `xfp` (as I don't know how to achieve this using `fp`) to make the assignments global.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xfp}

\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
  \xdef#2{\fpeval{round(#3,#1)}}%
}


% ---- Set dummy variable 
\const\MyVariable{1}

% ---- I want to loop over a list of keywords with the name of "MyVariable"
%.     Only one here for example.
\newcommand\MyVariableList{MyVariable}

\begin{document}
% ---- Start the loop and update values of constants in MyVariableList
\foreach \variable in \MyVariableList{%
   % ---- This updates the variable \MyVariable correctly
   \expandafter\const\csname\variable\endcsname{\csname\variable\endcsname +20}%
   % ---- Values of \MyVariable changes within the loop
   MyVariable inside the loop: \csname\variable\endcsname
}

MyVariable outside the loop: 
% ---- But not outside of it 
\MyVariable

\end{document}
```

The alternative would be to use a loop that doesn't group the iterations. This could be done with `\clist_map_inline:nn`:

```
\documentclass{article}

% get the function from expl3 and give it a document level name so that we can
% use it.
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \clistmap \clist_map_inline:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% ---- Helper function: easily add values to variables
%      Taken from a reply on stackoverflow that I can't find back...
%.     Works like so \const{VariableName}{value} ex: \const{CoolVariable}{5}
%.     and can then be called with \CoolVariable
%.     and can be updates with \const{CoolVariable}{CoolVariable+10}
\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
   \edef\temporary{round(#3}%
   \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
       \expandafter{\temporary:#1)}%
}


% ---- Set dummy variable 
\const{MyVariable}{1}
\const{YourVariable}{2}

\begin{document}
% ---- Start the loop and update values of constants in MyVariableList
\clistmap{MyVariable, YourVariable}
  {%
    % #1 will be the current loop iterations element
    % ---- This updates the variable \MyVariable correctly
    \const{#1}{#1 + 20}%
    % ---- Values of \MyVariable changes within the loop
    #1 inside the loop: \csname #1\endcsname\par
  }

MyVariable outside the loop: 
% ---- But not outside of it 
\MyVariable
\YourVariable

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Skillmon for your help ! 
I can confirm that both solution works well in the extended problem (though I had to add \usepackage{expl3} for the second answer).

I'm now looking at the difference between xfp and fp. 
Thanks again !


Edit: juste had a look at your expkv suite on CTAN. This is going to be really helpful in my project as well!

Comment: @MaxPimento while I'm glad that you find my `expkv`-packages interesting, I feel obligated to tell you that there are other interesting key=value packages which you might want to consider. Most noteworthy are maybe `l3keys` (also part of `expl3`) and `pgfkeys` (part of PGF, the base layer for the widely known Ti*k*Z). Both are way more widespread (well, they are much older so...). The only thing that (as of now) only `expkv` allows you to do is the things provided in `expkv-cs` (that package is afaik really unique with a simple yet powerful fully expandable interface).

Answer (score 1):

`\foreach` performs each cycle inside a group. This is a very common problem.

You *could* always do global assignment to your constants. By the way, the usage of `\global\edef` in your code is superfluous.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% ---- Helper function: easily set values to variables
\newcommand\const[3][0]{%
  \FPeval\temporary{round(#3:#1)}%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname #2\endcsname\temporary
}

% ---- Set dummy variable 
\const{MyVariable}{1}

% ---- I want to loop over a list of keywords with the name of "MyVariable"
%.     Only one here for example.
\newcommand\MyVariableList{MyVariable}

\begin{document}

% ---- Start the loop and update values of constants in MyVariableList
\foreach \variable in \MyVariableList{
   % ---- This updates the variable \MyVariable correctly
   \const{\csname variable\endcsname}{\csname variable\endcsname +20}
   
   % ---- Values of \MyVariable changes within the loop
   MyVariable inside the loop: \csname \variable\endcsname
}

MyVariable outside the loop: 
% ---- But not outside of it 
\MyVariable

\end{document}
```

[image]

I show here a different approach, where variables are called “by name” and not with the clumsy `\csname<name>\endcsname`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xfp} % easier than fp

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\const}{O{0}mm}
 {
  % allocate a variable if not yet existing
  \fp_if_exist:cF { l_pimento_const_#2_fp }
   { \fp_new:c { l_pimento_const_#2_fp } }
  % set the value
  \fp_set:cn { l_pimento_const_#2_fp } { round(#3,#1) }
 }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\eval}{m}
 {
  \fp_use:c { l_pimento_const_#1_fp }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\setconstants}{sO{0}mm}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__pimento_const_set:n { \const[#2]{##1}{#4} }
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {
    \clist_map_function:NN #3 \__pimento_const_set:n
   }
   {
    \clist_map_function:nN { #3 } \__pimento_const_set:n
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% ---- Set dummy variable 
\const{MyVariableA}{1}
\const{MyVariableB}{3}

\newcommand{\MyList}{MyVariableA,MyVariableB}

\begin{document}

\setconstants{MyVariableA,MyVariableB}{\eval{#1}+20}

\eval{MyVariableA}

\eval{MyVariableB}

\setconstants*[2]{\MyList}{\eval{#1}/2}

\eval{MyVariableA}

\eval{MyVariableB}

\fpeval{\eval{MyVariableA}+\eval{MyVariableB}}

\end{document}
```

The big advantage over `fp` is that operations are expandable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @egreg for your answer, I can confirm that the solution also work for my real-world problem. Neat answers where the variables are  called “by name”, updated my code accordingly. My account doesn't have enough reputation to mark the reply "as useful" but "My feedbak has been recorded". Have a great day!